# Can't format a 2TB external hard drive

Tags: 16.04, usb, external-hdd, disk-formatting

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. My kernel version is 4.4.0-201-generic. I've got an external 2TB USB hard drive. The vendor name is very new: Generial.

I can't get it to format as usual. Every time I try, the superblock contains lots of errors afterwards.

Do I need a kernel 5.x for that or a newer version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Sounds like the drive may be bad. how many is <lots of errors?

Comment: Also in case you were not aware support for 16.04 is EOL in April of this year time to upgrade to 18.04 or 20.04

Comment: I would try the external disk with another computer and/or operating system if possible.

Comment: Most drives, including external drives, have SMART; so I'd check it's health. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools  (gui tools can be used too; `gparted` for example though it's been awhile since I used 16.04/*xenial*)

Comment: By using the command `smartctl -i /dev/sdg` I'm getting this message:
/dev/sdg: Unknown USB bridge [0x048d:0x1234 (0x200)]

Comment: Looking around the web, it appears your external hard drive is an NVMe SSD wrapped in a USB-C enclosure. You might need to use a newer kernel to support that device. An easy way to test this would be to boot with a 20.04 or 20.10 Live USB stick, then connect the 2TB flash drive and see if it works. If it does, consider upgrading your Ubuntu installation 

Comment: Did you install a fresh **GPT partition table** on the drive (this will also wipe the drive)?

Comment: Does your device show up in  the output of **lsblk** ?

Comment: Does your device show up in Disks?  aka  Gnome Disks?

Comment: Are you changing the partition type to a modern one like **ext4**

Comment: I will backup my data and install Ubuntu 20. That's the best way.

Comment: another solution: I can buy another computer (cubietruck) for mining - and give access to the hard disk via network

Comment: I've been installing Ubuntu 20, but the problem still exists...

Comment: I've just seen it now: The USB drive is for Apple laptops. I'll sell it, I've just ordered another one.